# How to return full detailed error on express?

Tags: typescript, express, insomnia

I need to test a client that was created using the openapi generator from .yaml file. By now, for each endpoint, I'm creating another route to test using insomnia.

3 routes:

```js
digitalAccountRouter.post('/accounts/child', digitalAccountController.create);

digitalAccountRouter.get(
  '/accounts/main',
  digitalAccountController.mainAccountInformation,
);

digitalAccountRouter.patch(
  '/accounts/:financial_operation_key/owner',
  digitalAccountController.update,
);
```

[image: The routes on insomnia]

And a example of the implementation of one route:

```js
public create = async (request: Request, response: Response,next: NextFunction,): Promise<Response | void> => {
    const token = request.headers.authorization;
    const payload = request.body;
    payload.idempotencyKey = v4();

    const digitalAccountClient = new DigitalAccountApi(
      new Configuration({
        baseOptions: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token,
          },
        },
      }),
    );

    const apiResponse = await digitalAccountClient
      .accountsChildPost(payload)
      .catch(next);

    if (!apiResponse) {
      throw new Error('No reponse');
    }

    return response.status(200).json(apiResponse.data);
  };
```

Express error handling:

```js
app.use((err: any, _: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return response.status(err.status || 500).json({ err });
  }
  return response.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: 'Internal error' });
});
```

I'm using the `digitalAccountClient` to make a request of `accountsChildPost` endpoint and it is working. But I'm having problem with errors. If the request to the endpoint send a error I don't know how to pass. I would like to send the response with error as the endpoint sends. The problem is that the express is not sending the full error. If I `console.log(err)` it shows all the object on the terminal, but in insomnia only a part of the error arrives.

Part of the error:

[image]

What I receive in insomnia:

```json
{
  "err": {
    "message": "Request failed with status code 401",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 401\n    at createError (/home/ruan/Documents/incentiveme/hubfintech/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/home/ruan/Documents/incentiveme/hubfintech/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/ruan/Documents/incentiveme/hubfintech/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)",
    "config": {
      "url": "https://qacst-ppi.hubprepaid.com.br/partner-interface/accounts/207389168/owner",
      "method": "patch",
      "data": "{\"companyName\":\"PPI\",\"contact\":{\"email\":\"valeinterno@vale.com.br\",\"homePhone\":\"1131859402\",\"businessPhone\":\"1131859402\",\"mobilePhone\":\"1131859402\"},\"address\":{\"street\":\"Rua dos Testes\",\"number\":\"123\",\"district\":\"Tamboré\",\"zipcode\":\"06460080\",\"city\":\"Barueri\",\"state\":\"SP\"}}",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer Bearer",
        "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.1",
        "Content-Length": 274
      },
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "maxBodyLength": -1
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be because you use `res.status` and you should use `res.send` to send the error as a response? Example: `res.status(500).send('Something broke!')`.

Comment: @Almaju I tried this but nothing still the same thing. Thanks for the tip!